# RubyGems plugin to tame a big ball of already-installed gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Maybe someone knows if this sort of RubyGems plugin exists already, before I try to sink a lot of time into writing one myself.

I'm not using RVM* <del>or Bundler</del> *(edit: see thread in comments)*, so I have a big ball of system gems installed.  I want to sort out which ones are gems I really want to use, which ones are dependencies that have to be there for the gems I really want to use, and which ones are just junk that can be cleaned up.

If anyone is familiar with Gentoo, I'm thinking of something similar to Gentoo's package management, but for RubyGems instead--a way to tag a small list of gems I really *want* to keep, then run a command that can go through all of my gems and clean up the ones that aren't dependencies of those gems.  A "@world" set for RubyGems, in other words.

*RVM isn't an option for me anyway, because I have to use Microsoft Windows.

Comment: Have you check pik? link: https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/

Comment: Yes, I have used Pik, and I like Pik.  But I don't think it's applicable to this specific problem.  I want a RubyGems plugin that can keep track of which gems I've specifically requested to be installed, and thus sort out gems that are important dependencies vs. gems that are totally orphaned.  (I did find `gem-orphan`, but I think it is too far out of date to be of any use.)

Comment: Are you sure you can't use Bundler?  It sounds like the right tool for the job. :)

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I love Bundler to death. But what I want to do is clean up system gems that are already installed on my system.

Comment: Actually, in a way, Bundler is the _cause_ of this situation I'm in. By default, Bundler installs gems in the system gem directory. And I work with a lot of projects that use Bundler. So now I have a bunch of gems installed in the system and it's difficult to be sure which ones are supposed to be there and which ones I can safely delete.

Comment: Could you check the access time of gem directories? In unix you can use the stat command, but since you want to run it in Windows you could write a ruby script using the [File::Stat](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html) class. Check for gems that haven't been accessed after a certain date, for instance.

Comment: I'll have to remember that technique when I write my RubyGems plugin. Thanks. (I just don't want to write my RubyGems plugin if someone already has written one. It's beginning to sound like no one has done.)

Comment: @L2G Old post but for any travelers from google. 2015 and Unfortunately the default behavior of bundler is to still install Gemfile depens in the global scope. I wrote a bash script to prevent me from doing a `bundle install` without specifying a path or marking the deployment option. https://gist.github.com/SephVelut/4b49100e7f9b50d996e6

Answer (score 0):

If you install graphviz, then you can run`bundle viz` this will produce a dot notation mapping of the dependencies and you can use that to trace dependencies down to those gem's you actually need to have installed (but only those that you have installed via bundler).

```
bundle viz --format=dot
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am trying to sort through the Ruby system gems, though, not the gems from any one Bundler-controlled project. I appreciate the tip, though--I forgot the `viz` command was in there!